# How to fix the problem when installing @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue-cli

First i installed npm and vue from the official site and npm worked well when installing other packages like cli-service and cli-eslint. but cli-plugin-unit-jest just failed.
i use the following command:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest@^4.4.6
```

but got the following error:

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     undefined,
npm WARN cleanup     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: rimraf: missing path
npm WARN cleanup         at rimraf (D:\Software\NodeJs\node_global\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:54:3)
...
npm WARN cleanup       generatedMessage: false,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
npm WARN cleanup       actual: undefined,
npm WARN cleanup       expected: true,
npm WARN cleanup       operator: '=='
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Software\NodeJs\node_global\node_modules\@vue\cli-plugin-unit-jest\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! �ڴ˽��������һ������һ����Ŀ����Ҫ���ò������ɣ������ӡ�-m�����ء�
npm ERR!   Backend.cc
npm ERR! D:\Software\NodeJs\node_global\node_modules\@vue\cli-plugin-unit-jest\node_modules\canvas\src\backend\Backend.h(3,10): fatal error C1083: �޷������ļ�: ��cairo.h��: No such file or directory [D:\Software\NodeJs\ node_global\node_modules\@vue\cli-plugin-unit-jest\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
...
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `D:\Software\MSVS2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Software\NodeJs\node_global\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Software\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\Software\\NodeJs\\node_global\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Software\NodeJs\node_global\node_modules\@vue\cli-plugin-unit-jest\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

what is the problem? Are there any dependencies i haven't installed?

Comment: Have the same problem here on macOS. Even on new project this error occurred.
This happen only on Node 16.1.0. On Node 14 it works.